# XCODE7とOSX 10.11 El CapitanでCocoaPodsをインストール時エラー

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode7

```
UserName-no-MacBook:~ Junichi$ sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj
```

上記のエラーが出てしまい、先に進めません。

解決策わかる方、教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: [Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj Issue #3692 CocoaPods/CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692)

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。